# Can we track down destroy annoying USB mouse/keyboard issue once and for all?

Tags: windows-10, usb, keyboard, mouse, freeze

For the life of me I don't know what's going on here! Sometime about 3-5 months ago I started experiencing issues where my wireless USB mouse/keyboard will just randomly freeze. It will hang for about 3-8 seconds non-responsive to any movement from mouse, nor input from keyboard. It seems to gradually get worse as usage goes on, but always seems to peak just shy of unusable.

I don't usually run many apps. This machine is mostly for light web browsing and local development.

At any given time I'll usually have VS Code open running a couple of powershell terminals, and a couple of browsers open (Chrome, FireFox) with anywhere from 1-5 tabs  (including FireFox Dev Tools). And that's pretty much it. Startup services are minimal and other than the bloat from the windows services, I don't really have anything (obvious) running behind the scenese.

RAM is almost always around 30-40% of 16GB. CPU hardly ever goes above 50% (even during the mouse/keyboard issues.

For the sake of brevity, I'll not list EVERYTHING I've tried to track this down, but I'll list a few things here, and let me know if you have any ideas:

- New graphics card Switched
- USB around to different ports
- Installing Windows updates
- Rolling Back to previous Windows builds
- Tweaking just about every setting imaginable

I've done just about everything shy of buying a new mouse, which I'm pretty close to doing, but feel like it won't do any good.

There's something happening on this box and I want to know what it is.

Anyone have any thoughts on how I could go about tracking this down?! Let me know your thoughts/ideas!!

**EDIT -- Add Hardware Spec---**

- Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6600 CPU @ 3.30GHz
- MotherBoard: Asus Z170 Pro4
- RAM: 16GB DDR4-2133 - G.SKILL Ripjaws 4 Series
- GPU: Radeon RX 550
- SSD: Mushkin Enhanced Reactor 2.5" 1TB SATA III MLC Internal SSD
- Monitors: 3 (2 x 27", 1 x 23")
- Logitech M310 Wireless Keyboard/Mouse Combo
- Yamaha Audiogram6 USB Audio Interface (External Sound Card)
- 500W Power Supply

Can't think of anything else...

Comment: What's your hardware? Do you have USB OTG on your phone or a laptop?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Phone is never connected to PC and hardly ever any USB devices other mouse/keyboard. Although I do have an old Yamaha Audiogram USb external sound card hoooked up, but that's been in play forever and never had any issues before. I also have a 4 port USB-hub connected, but nothing ever plugged in there. Removing it makes no difference.

Comment: Does anything strange appear in Event Viewer when it happens?

Comment: Could it be external RF interference? Wireless mice usually operate as Bluetooth devices. Try moving everything to another room, away from cell phones and other possible sources of RF.

Comment: Ahh good question. So spent a good day or two watching event viewer, turning debug logs, etc. and trying to correlate the timing of the issue with any logged event. Although I was seeing some unique log entries, I sadly was unable to gather enough evidence to be able to point the finger at any of those. The timing between the logged events and the device issues were just too far off and not occurring as often as the freezing.

Comment: The question is it a system stall or a mouse stall?  Have you tried **chkdsk /r c:** to verify your not running into bad sectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you've honed nearly everything down software-wise; it's likely your issue is related to hardware. The best option at the moment would be to try out your mouse/keyboard on another computer (if you don't have one at the moment, try them out at a local library's computer or something of that nature).

If it works there, you may want to try a few more things - as others have mentioned, move all other electronics away from the room and then try the keyboard and mouse out. Try using them one at a time (it's possible it could be a driver issue related to them interfering with each other). You may want to consider spraying your motherboard with compressed air, as this can often solve some strange issues going on with IO.

My final suggestion before a full replace of the motherboard would be reflashing your BIOS; once again, this can solve many odd IO issues.